# JSON: TypeError: Decimal('34.3') is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json

I am running an SQL query which returns a list of Decimals. When I try to convert this into JSON i get the type error.

The query:

```
res = db.execute("""
SELECT CAST ((SUM(r.SalesVolume)/1000.0) AS decimal(6,1))
FROM RawData r
INNER JOIN Product p
ON r.ProductId = p.ProductId 
INNER JOIN Calendar c
ON r.DayId = c.DayId
WHERE c.WeekCodeInYear BETWEEN 1 AND 12
AND 
c.YearId = 2014
GROUP BY c.WeekCodeInYear """)
```

Result List:

```
[Decimal('34.3'), Decimal('50.9'), Decimal('31.5'), Decimal('23.3'), Decimal('19
.7'), Decimal('56.9'), Decimal('43.8'), Decimal('35.2'), Decimal('29.2'), Decima
l('43.7'), Decimal('42.6'), Decimal('23.4')]
```

Code:

```
for row in res:
    testlist.append (row[0])
    print testlist

list = json.dumps(testlist)
```

And the I get the `Unable to serialize error`
Tried looking up online, no much help.
Please note that the final list would go as input data to a chart.

Comment: `Decimal object` is not json serializable. show us the execution result of `print testlist`

Comment: @LittleQ The result list above is the execution of `testlist`

Comment: got your point. BTW, `list` is a built-in type, better not use it as a variable name

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the error says, the `Decimal` type is not able to be serialized directly into JSON.  Considering casting the `Decimal` into a `float` if you wish to keep that as a number, however you may get rounding errors.  i.e.

```
for row in res:
    testlist.append(float(row[0]))
```

Or alternatively build the list using list comprehension, this time I cast to `str`.

```
testlist = [str(row[0]) for row in res]
```

The latter is an appropriate representation as the `Decimal` type can be unambiguously represented by `str`.  You can grab the original value like so

```
from decimal import Decimal
jlist = json.dumps(testlist)  # don't use list as it's predefined type
new_list = json.loads(jlist)
new_dlist = [Decimal(s) for s in new_list]
```

`new_dlist` should be identical to the original `templist`.

Comment: If the input is already within 1 decimal digit _always_ then you will always have that precision.  Extracting that back out will require constructing the `Decimal` with the correct amount of precision.

Answer (score 22):

Use a override `default`:

```
import json
from decimal import Decimal

def default(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
        return str(obj)
    raise TypeError("Object of type '%s' is not JSON serializable" % type(obj).__name__)

json.dumps(testlist, default=default)
```

Or just do `str` on `Decimal` object:

```
for row in res:
    testlist.append (str(row[0]))
json.dumps(testlist)
```

Comment: the latter one is more simple.

Comment: I found extending the default kind of tricky, and I found someone's library doing it for more types in an organized fashion.  https://pypi.org/project/json-default/  Also I wanted to store mine as a float, so I changed your line 6 to `float(obj)` .

Comment: Also like in the linked example at the top `SimpleJson` supports `Decimal` nicely.  https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson