# Avoiding "Decimal('value') in cursor.fetchall

Tags: python, json, list, psycopg2

In a Python script, a `cursor.fetchall` command is returning a list of tuples, some elements of which are marked as e.g. `Decimal('0.50')` instead of just `0.50`.

```
myList= [(1, 'string1', None, None, 'string2', 0, 'string3'),
(1,   'string1',   Decimal('0.50'),   Decimal('2.5'),   'string2',   3,   'string3')]
```

The reason I'd like the latter form (i.e. just  `0.50`) is that I'm trying to send the list using `print(json.dumps(result))`, which currently returns `TypeError: Decimal('0.50') is not JSON serializable`.

Is there a direct way to strip away this "type" information? I've been turning around on this without success, and I find previous related questions only cover cases where all elements are of the same type (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202956/json-typeerror-decimal34-3-is-not-json-serializable)). Thanks for any tips!

Comment: This isn't "type information", a `Decimal` object is different from an `int` or ` float`, it is its own class. `decimal.Decimal`. You can probably just do `float(Decimal('0.05')`

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960516/python-json-serialize-a-decimal-object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way I overcame this issue.

First, I convert the query result into a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(query_data)
```

Then, I simply convert the troublesome columns to string:

```
df[2] = [str(r) for r in df[2]]
```

Finally, I convert the dataframe to a csv string:

```
df_csv = df.to_csv(sep=',', index = False, header = False)
```

And this can be used with no error in `print(json.dumps(result))`.

Pretty specific workaround, but thought I'd post it anyway to provide at least one answer to the problem.